# Mean.js: Add a users CRUD module accessed only by admin users

Tags: yeoman, crud, mean, meanjs

So, when we create a Mean.js app using the yo generator, there's a User module by default, that manages authentication, sign up, sign in, profile settings, etc.
We also have the option to add roles to the users in the users model, admin and user roles are set by default.
Users can self register to the app by default, now let's say I want to use the admin user to do CRUD ops on Users (create, read, update, delete new users, and make queries such as list users) and disable the sign up option for common users so only the admin can register new users.

I thought about two options:

- create a CRUD module with yeoman (but this would cause trouble with the existing User module, that manages all this auth stuff)
- do everything from scratch, like adding all the controlers, routes, and all the stuff needed (but this would take a lot of time and it could create lots of bugs cause I may forget something)

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

[Mean.js 0.4.0](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/tree/0.4.0) is the most recent version and it will have an admin module incorporated in a near future. I implemented one in my app similar to the one in this [pull request](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/pull/615). Take a look and see if it works for you.